# Expanding ${var} references in a JavaScript string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Learning something beyond vanilla JavaScript and the book I'm reading is telling me a statement like:

```
let someVar = 'Happy';
console.log('I hope you have a ${someVar} day.');
```

Should display 'Happy'? in the log or an alert or possibly anywhere.

It doesn't work.  I'm using FireFox Dev Ed and I just get a line with the entire:

```
${someVar}
```

in it.  Any guidance...  Is this a weird transpiler issue or ES6+ issue?

Comment: You need to use backticks instead of single quotes. These are called [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: Refer This Link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need backticks surrounding the string there in order for the interpreter to properly interpret it as a template literal.

```js
let someVar = 'Happy';
console.log(`I hope you have a ${someVar} day.`);
```

When you have a normal string, you can use single quotes `'` or double quotes `"`, but when you're using a template literal, you must always use backticks `.

You can also use backticks anyway even if you aren't interpolating any variables inside, just so you don't have to escape quote characters, for example.

Comment: Thanks...  I actually did hear something about back ticks before but I didn't know where they applied...  Thanks for the help!